# COUNT function with padded numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm sorry if this has already been answered, but I haven't found it in my searches. Though, it does seem like it should be relatively simple.

I'm trying to find duplicates in a table. Some of the data in there is from a legacy database that we've integrated into this one. The rules we have now weren't enforced back then, so we're in the process of cleaning it up now.

Sadly, our project numbers are strings. Some project numbers have leading zeroes while others do not. Also some Project Numbers have letters in them.

I need to find projects which have the same root number regardless of leading zeroes. So for instance:

```
PROJ_NUM  
021523  
000345  
21523  
345  
00345
```

I want it to count 2 for project `021523` and 3 for `000345`.

My current code is as follows:

```
SELECT LPAD(PROJ_NUM, 6, '0') PROJ_NUM
       , PROJ_TYPE
       , COUNT(LPAD(PROJ_NUM, 6, '0')) COUNT  
FROM TABLE  
HAVING COUNT(LPAD(PROJ_NUM, 6, '0')) > 1  
GROUP BY LPAD(PROJ_NUM, 6, '0'), PROJ_TYPE  
ORDER BY PROJ_TYPE, PROJ_NUM
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Proj_Type is necessary for this query, due to there being different project types with the same project number, which I don't want to count as duplicates.

Edit: I've discovered that part of the problem I was having involved trailing spaces with project numbers. My code as it stands is currently:

```
SELECT PROJ_NUM
    , PROJ_TYPE
    , CNT
FROM (
    SELECT LPAD(PROJ_NUM, 6, '0') PROJ_NUM
    , PROJ_TYPE
    , COUNT(PROJ_NUM) CNT
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY LPAD(PROJ_NUM, 6, '0'), PROJ_TYPE
)
WHERE CNT > 1
AND PROJ_TYPE IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY PROJ_TYPE, PROJ_NUM
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Is it  erroring, or not giving the results you expect? You haven’t shown the project type for those project numbers, so maybe your grouping shouldn’t include the type? (Which would mean you couldn’t show the project type in the select list as you are now; there are other approaches if you need to),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created [a SQLFiddle test case using your data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ec06c/1) and it returns the results you want.

However, I made up values for `PROJ_TYPE` because you didn't provide them in your sample data. I assigned each project the same Type, which is why my query works. Perhaps in your real data the "duplicate" projects have different types? If so, your query would return no rows.

Two ways of working around this. The first is obvious: remove `PROJ_TYPE` from the query. But if you want to see the Type too you can use a sub-query with an analytic count to get this information: note that this query returns one row per Project:

```
select proj_num, proj_type from (
    SELECT LPAD(PROJ_NUM, 6, '0') PROJ_NUM
           , PROJ_TYPE
           , count(*) over (partition by LPAD(PROJ_NUM, 6, '0')) cnt 
    FROM t23 
    )
where cnt > 1
ORDER BY proj_num, proj_type
/
```

---

This may not the solution you're looking for. If that is the case please **edit your question** providing a clearer explanation of the problem you're trying to solve and sufficient example data for us to reproduce it.

Comment: Thank you for putting in the time to help me with this. I appreciate it. I made an edit to my original post to try to clarify the importance of Proj_Type (different project types can have the same project number and I don't want these to count as duplicates). I made some adjustments to this, but it seems to have given me the most accurate results. My code as it stands currently is shown as an edit in my original post. Can you help me understand why this code with a subquery gives me better results than what I originally posted? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your project numbers are numeric, you can use TO_NUMBER() to get rid of leading zeroes.

```
SELECT COUNT(0), TO_NUMBER(PROJ_NUM) AS PROJ_NUM FROM TABLE GROUP BY TO_NUMBER(PROJ_NUM)
```

Comment: Sadly, our project numbers are strings.

Comment: @BlueJacket - but are they all strings of just digits, so could be converted to numbers for this grouping? (Of course, then you’d have to wonder why the column data type is not number; and if they must be strings why the formatting is not enforced...)

Comment: @AlexPoole Some Project Numbers do have letters in them. Some of the data in there is from a legacy database that we've integrated into this one. The rules we have now weren't enforced back then, so we're in the process of cleaning it up now.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you strip out the leading zeros using `ltrim()`:

```
SELECT LTRIM(PROJ_NUM, '0') as PROJ_NUM, COUNT(*) as cnt  
FROM TABLE  
GROUP BY LTRIM(PROJ_NUM, '0')
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Nothing in your question involves the project type, so that is not included in the query.

Comment: The OP's code works as it is; most likely their problem is related to the inclusion of the PROJ_TYPE column, which - depending on their data -  probably produces a different result from the one they're expecting.